# Can "Remove Unnecessary Usings" in VS2017 be customized?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

VS2017 includes a feature to remove all unnecessary `using` statements from the top of a .cs file. While useful, I'd like to configure it to not remove System.Linq even if it is unused.  Otherwise I have to add it back in as soon as I need to use an extension method.

Is there any way to change the default behavior?